# Agile Web Development With Rails example displays image over text

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I'm reading a book (*Agile Web Development With Rails*) and I'm encountering a problem on page 96.

I've stuck to the code in the book exactly, but I get this.

> [image: Rendered Output]

I know another way to approach this is to use a table, but I want to know if there is another solution first.

Comment: The image and the text are black, maybe the text is above the image (and the image is a CSS background image). Use firebug or something similar to inspect the HTML and CSS.

Comment: the stylesheet code : http://media.pragprog.com/titles/rails4/code/rails32/depot_d/app/assets/stylesheets/store.css.scss

the view :
http://media.pragprog.com/titles/rails4/code/rails32/depot_d/app/views/store/index.html.erb

Comment: and here is how the desired output is : http://img824.imageshack.us/img824/768/45905561.png

sorry about multiple comments... spam prevention allows only 2 hyperlinks per comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would organize these comments using divs. The first div to house the image and comment. The second div to house the image. And the third to house the comment.

The html:

```
<div class="comment-container">

  <div class="comment-img">
    <!whatever code you use to pull images from the database>
  </div><!ENDcomment-img>

  <div class="comment-field">
    <!whatever code you use to pull comment content from the database>
  </div><!ENDcomment-field>

</div><!ENDcomment-container>
```

The CSS:

```
 .comment-container{
     padding: 5px; 
     border-bottom: 1px dashed #009fe4; 
     margin: 2px 0 5px 0;
  }

 .comment-img{
     float: left;
     width: 80px;
     height: auto;
  }

 .comment-field{
     width: 700px;
     height: auto;
     padding: 0 0 0 10px;
  }
```

I hope this helps out.

@subm0ral

Answer (score 0):

It's the `position: absolute;` in the rule `img` of your CSS that make the image above the text. See [help](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_positioning.asp)